# Basic geometry problem question (Segment intersections?)

Tags: geometry

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eIiK.png)
[image]

So, **I was able to solve this problem**, but what I'm curious of is once we solve the variables can I extend point F to line BC making Triangle ABX? I imagine an extension of point F would have to lie on BC at some point and intersect it. And because we're told that the x variables are part of a tri-section, each angle would have to be the same measure.

When I first saw the problem I wanted to extend it and try and prove triangle ABX might be isosceles, but my instructor informed me that it was not possible, which I can see why now. But what about AFTER the variables are discovered, shouldn't that allow us to see where line AF would extend to?

Or, would I need this shape to lie on a coordinate plane to be able to determine all this? Thanks in advance!

Edit to clarify: I want to determine where the extension of segment AF would intersect segment BC making the Triangle ABX (where X is the new point extended from segment AF). Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Are you wanting to extend segment AF until it intersects segment BC? Your first paragraph is not clear ("an extension of point F" makes no sense).

Comment: Sorry if I was vague, but yes, I want to extend segment AF until it intersects segment BC.

Comment: It's not actually known whether $F$ is inside the quadrilateral, from the definitions. $x$ and $y$ are not explicitly solved for.

Comment: Hm, do you mean because everything isn't coplanar we can't know?

Comment: No, even assuming coplanar, because we don't know the lengths of the sides.

Comment: I see your point, thank you for replying and helping, Joffan!

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “discovering” or “solving for” the variables here. The point of the original problem is that even though the values of angles $x$ and $y$ themselves cannot be determined, their sum is constant.

Answer (score 0):

If $AF\cap BC=\{X\}$ then $X$ can be placed not on segment $BC$.

Also, $x$ changes and you can not prove, what you want.

Comment: Well, I mean I solved the original problem of finding <AFD. My above question is more out of a personal curiousity. It's hard to visualize where segment AF will intersect on segment BC. That's what I'm asking about, hah.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question OP asked.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply! Could you clarify on why x 'changes'? I thought because <BAD was tri-sected each x degree measure would be fixed into equal partitions? Also, as a side question, does this imply that there can exist an extension of segment AF to segment BC to make an isosceles triangle AFX or is it just outright NOT possible?

Comment: @Insalubrious Sophist Because you know a value of $x+y$ and you don't know what is a value of $x$.

Comment: Ooooh! That makes perfect sense now, Micheal, thanks!

Comment: @Insalubrious Sophist You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

By changing the lengths $AB$ and $CD$ (or equivalently $BC$ and $DA$), we can manipulate the intersection of $AF$ with $BC$ or $CD$ within wide limits. Quite apart from the difficulty of not knowing the individual angle values of $x$ or $y$, only the sum.

It's reasonable to assume the figure is on a plane, though. That way the intersections are somewhat predictable.

Comment: I'm not sure why the sum of x + y vs the values of x and y individually never crossed my mind. A subtle, but interesting point that blew over my head! Well, maybe not so subtle, considering you're substituting for (2x+2y) in 180 - (2x+2y), hah.